# WP81 Create XAML style to target all pages in the app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, targettype

I want to set the background image for all the pages in my windows phone 8.1 app (RT not Silverlight) by declaring a style that targets the page.

Like this:

```
        <Style TargetType="Page">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
```

It seems to work in the designer, as I see the red background on all my pages. However when I actually run the app the background is missing (black, blank) not red.

Some of the pages in my app derive from a custom type (which derives from Page) and I know that TargetType doesn't inherit. So I added additional styles for these:

```
        <Style TargetType="local:ViewBase">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
```

Again, in the designer I see the Red (tho strangely enough I also saw the red when I was only targeting Page). Upon launch again however, the background is not Red, but blank (black).

I could easily give it a key, or add the Background property to every page and bind it to a resource, but I thought the whole point of Implicit styles was to allow me to override every instance of the control...

Can I not target a Page for a default (implicit) style?

Comment: Set the Grid.Background of the root grid instead of Page.Background. I think you will find more reliable results.

Comment: agreed, setting background of page consistently returns screwy results :(

Answer (score 0):

aha: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/bb927601-2e3e-45ac-afe8-621df57b9738/why-does-style-targettypepage-not-work-in-an-application?forum=winappswithcsharp

looks like this is a known issue, boo I say! I'll set the background to a resource then.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you override brush in application resource

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Name="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="RED"/>
```